# C# winforms listbox can't get the right value

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

With a listbox called lbcustomers, I have the following:

```
DataTable Customers = GetAllCustomers();
        lbCustomers.DataSource = Customers;
        lbCustomers.DisplayMember = "lastName";
        lbCustomers.ValueMember = "Cell";
```

The last names are properly displayed. But using the following during an event, I am getting my second list box filled with "System.Data.DataRowView"

```
if (lbCustomers.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lbCustomers.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(lbCustomers.SelectedItems[i]))
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(lbCustomers.SelectedItems[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have multiple sources of data coming into listBox2, so I just want to get the "Cell" value from the selected lbCustomer items.

Comment: Have you also set ``the `DisplayMember` property of `listBox2`, otherwise you it will display the output of `ToString()` which is what you are seeing?

Comment: probably do set `listBox2.DisplayMember = "lastName";`

Comment: Okay, so just so I understand this better, `lbCustomers.SelectedItems[i]` passes the entire row?  What does ValueMember actually do then?